# Determining the inverse discrete cosine transform II (IDCT-II)

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I am preparing myself for my upcoming math exam and one of the preparation exercises includes

(i) showing that the DCT-II is invertible

(ii) determining the formula of the inverse DCT-II

The DCT-II is given by

$$ y_k = \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} x_j  \cdot \cos(\pi k(j + 1/2)/n), \qquad k=0\dots n-1 $$

I started by converting this equation into a matrix equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots \\[0.3em]
y_k \\[0.3em]
\vdots
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cdots && \cdots  && \cdots \\
\vdots && \cos(\pi k(j + 1/2)/n) && \vdots \\
\cdots && \cdots  && \cdots \\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots \\[0.3em]
x_k \\[0.3em]
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now the next step would be to show the existence of

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cdots && \cdots  && \cdots \\
\vdots && \cos(\pi k(j + 1/2)/n) && \vdots \\
\cdots && \cdots  && \cdots \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$

and to finally determine the inverted matrix. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider this approach: 
http://www-math.mit.edu/~gs/papers/dct.pdf

The idea is that the dct vectors are eigenvector a of a particular difference operator related to ODE (laplacian eigenvector). inverse is also easy to show once you have orthogonality.

Another approach might be relation to FFT.